# getting string values as well in textbox while using Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, html.textboxfor

In my partial view I have passed some list of strings from a method in controller
Here is my partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

@foreach(var names in Model)
{
    
    <div class="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>names)</div>
    <br/>
}
```

Here is how it looks in browser

[image]

Why am I getting the texts in textbox?
I mean I would want them there but as placeholder not default text.
How can I not have those values and just have a plane textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to change initial value:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => names, new { Value = "" })
```

Comment: thanks but I wouldn't be able to use placeholder there than. Is there some other option that would allow me to use placeholder as well? or I could use html.labelfor(m=>names) but then in label i don't get the value of name but I get text name. Weird

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => names, new { Value = "", placeholder = "someplaceholder" })`